# Is there a system agnostic treasure table?

Tags: system-agnostic, treasure, generator

Many of the existing treasure generators are very tied into a campaign. They would include very specific treasures like "Wand of Ghoul Touch" or "1,500 gp". Even the gold pieces amount isn't very helpful because they depend on a specific ruleset.

I would like something that would work with most kinds of generic fantasy campaign. Maybe something suited for roguelikes? [Tavern Maker](http://tavernmaker.de/eng/men-eng-inf.htm) does a good job of generating pickpocketable items, but it doesn't generate a whole hoard.

Some common things would be things like magical armor, masterwork weapons, or artwork.